# Summation of Trig Functions in Python

Tags: python, function, sum, trigonometry

Can you do a summation of a trig function in python? For example, sum of cos(2x) over two iterations. Thank you!

```
def function_name(phi1, phi2, distance):
"""
phi_1 - List of first angles [radians]
phi_2 - List of second angles [radians]
distance - List of all distances

Note: All inputs must be the same length
Note: All inputs must be NumPy arrays!
"""

phi_1=[0.698132, 0.872665]
phi_2=[0.872665, 0.698132]
distance

sig_phi = 1

#Setup exponent array and get squared distance

exponents= np.ones_like(distance) * 2
dist_sq= np.power(distance,exponents)

mat1=[[np.sum(np.divide((1+np.cos(2*phi1)),(2*dist_sq))),-1.0 * np.sum(np.divide((np.sin(2*phi1)),(2*dist_sq)))], [np.sum(np.divide(1-np.cos(2*phi1)),(2*dist_sq)),-1.0 * np.sum(np.divide((np.sin(2*phi1)),(2*dist_sq)))]]
mat1 *= 1/sig2_phi**2

mat2=[[np.sum(np.divide((1+np.cos(2*phi2)),(2*dist_sq))),-1.0 * np.sum(np.divide((np.sin(2*phi2)),(2*dist_sq)))], [np.sum(np.divide(1-np.cos(2*phi2)),(2*dist_sq)),-1.0 * np.sum(np.divide((np.sin(2*phi2)),(2*dist_sq)))]]
mat2 *= 1/sig2_phi**2

return mat1,mat2
print (mat1, mat2, distance)
```

I want to keep the distance as a variable- so I can see what distance maximizes the determinant of the matrix. I am not getting any results when I run the code in my terminal. Does anyone know what I should do?

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly you mean, and post your attempt at solving the problem?

Comment: The sum of cosine over n periods is 0. Do you just mean to integrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but certainly each individual piece is quite simple to accomplish in Python. 
By using the `sum()` function with the trigonometric functions provided in the `math` module together in a list comprehension, it should be relatively simple to accomplish. For the example you give,

```
from math import *
iters = [1, 2]
summation = sum(cos(2*x) for x in iters)
```

, should do the trick.

Also, I'd recommend being more thorough in your questions in the future. It is frowned upon to ask questions with no evidence of having attempted the problem already.

Comment: Thank you! And I will, just am very new to python

Comment: Hi, I am struggling plugging in two specific angles into x and getting a result. Nothing prints when I run the code. Can you please help me? So I guess my question would be how do I go about plugging in two specific angles into the summation equation?

Comment: @AnnCatherineBokinsky Why don't you post your code somewhere and I would be happy to help. It's hard to diagnose an issue just from reading about it. One thing I'll say though, all the math module python trig functions default to radians rather than degrees, so be wary of that.